# DataTypes.DECIMAL causing may be causing error: 'Unknown column' in Sequelize auto-migration command

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

Using Sequelize (ORM for Node.js), I am trying to add a column to a table with a data type of 'DECIMAL'. I have been able to add other columns to other identical tables with other data types of of DATE and STRING, but this changeColumn function will not execute. Instead I get the 'ERROR: Unknown column 'default_price' in 'category' when I try the command sequelize db:migrate. I'm quite new to developing so I don't have much experience with Sequelize yet.

````
I run this command:

L05HandsOn>sequelize db:migrate

Sequelize CLI [Node: 8.11.4, CLI: 5.4.0, ORM: 4.43.0]

Loaded configuration file "config\config.json".
Using environment "development".
sequelize deprecated String based operators are now deprecated. Please use Symbol based operators for better security, read more at http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:242:13
File: _current.json does not match pattern: /\.js$/
File: _current_bak.json does not match pattern: /\.js$/
File: _current.json does not match pattern: /\.js$/
File: _current_bak.json does not match pattern: /\.js$/
File: _current.json does not match pattern: /\.js$/
File: _current_bak.json does not match pattern: /\.js$/
== 2-category_Decimal_migration: migrating =======
[#0] execute: changeColumn

ERROR: Unknown column 'default_price' in 'category

My migration.js file looks like this:

'use strict';

var Sequelize = require('sequelize');

/**
 * Actions summary:
 *
 * changeColumn "default_price" on table "category"
 *
 **/

var info = {
    "revision": 2,
    "name": "category_Decimal_migration",
    "created": "2019-05-17T01:56:58.412Z",
    "comment": ""
};

var migrationCommands = [{
    fn: "changeColumn",
    params: [
        "category",
        "default_price",
        {
            "type": Sequelize.DECIMAL(2, 2),
            "field": "default_price",
            "allowNull": false
        }
    ]
}];

module.exports = {
and so on ... 

When I run the 'sequelize db:migrate' command I expect to see

```[#0] execute: changeColumn
2-category_Decimal_migration: migrated (0.XXXs)```
````

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the fix that was needed was to run an addColumn command before changeColumn--I was attempting to change a column that didn't exist. Since auto-Sequelize commands perform a lot of behind the scenes changes in the form of migration files, it's important to follow the file creation steps in order--Sequelize won't exactly tell you that you did the step out of sequence, but will create new migration files I think. This could be misleading as a migration could eventually be migrated if all was in place. Inthis case the migration could not be executed due to user error in the basic order of model creation steps.